# site's system not coming up correctly

Tags: control-panel, config

Thanks for helping me with my htaccess issue before and I hope you can help me once more.

A little background, I am attempting to have my local machine and staging mimic the production site.

I have been able to make the local machine work perfectly and I was on my way to do the same for the staging server.

I had logged into the site dev.example.com/system and I was configuring everything to point to dev.example.com, instead of the production site - www.example.com

After submitting the Admin> General Configuration - I briefly saw a prompt about config, but somehow it disappeared before I read.

Now, going into system looks like an html file that is missing a css file - like a directory tree.

Firebug in firefox is showing that it can not find items in the themes folder.

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://dev.example.com/themes/cp_themes/default/css/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css?v=1400856569"
```

jquery...0856569

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://dev.example.com/themes/cp_themes/default/css/global.css?v=1400856569"
```

global...0856569

```
 "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://dev.example.com/themes/javascript/compressed/jquery/jquery.js?v=1400856579"
```

jquery...0856579

etc...

Any ideas - thanks in advance

Comment: You would benefit from installing [FocusLab's Master Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config). It will allow you to maintain multiple environments using configuration variables rather than updating settings manually in the database.

Comment: Have you checked for the presence of the file in the error?

Comment: Yeah, all the files are there, which leads me to believe that I must have typed in a bad path to the themes. Without being able to use example.com/system, can you tell which tables or files I can update the correct information?

Comment: I was still able to click on Admin> General Configuration link which showed a very basic form, when I entered the correct path, I was once again told that I had to set the config.php to 666, which I did and everything is fine. Thanks guys - I am a true newbie to ExpressionEngine - thanks for being there

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comments:

I was still able to click on Admin> General Configuration link which showed a very basic form, when I entered the correct path, I was once again told that I had to set the config.php to 666, which I did and everything is fine. Thanks guys - I am a true newbie to ExpressionEngine - thanks for being there